# unity and ios - get user's phone number

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

I'm building a game for ios on unity3d, and I want to know how downloaded the game so I want to get permissions to the user's iphone, and get the phone number of the user and send it back to me.

I want the user's phone number or the user's IMEI number for example.

Is it possible doing that through Unity and IOS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can **NOT** get anything like IMIE number or Phone number from iOS any more if you want to submit app to App Store. There is not any public api available for this.

You can get carrier info like carrierName, country code, network code- but these are not unique to device.

You can check what information available from UIDevice from :
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice

To check what you can get from core telephony
https://developer.apple.com/reference/coretelephony

To check what you can get from System Configuration:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/systemconfiguration

Comment: where can I see what can I get from the device?

Comment: Added few links in answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only info you can get is the identifierForVendor.

The identifier for vendor is :

An alphanumeric string that uniquely identifies a device to the app’s vendor.

Not Sure you can do this in Unity.

Objective C code to do it is :

```
UIDevice *device = [[UIDevice alloc]init];
NSString *idForVend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device identifierForVendor]];
NSLog(@"%@",idForVend);
```

If you want to get more info about the user, you should ask him to fill out forms field in your app. Then your app can send back the info to you.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: is there any other way to get the any unique info of the device? imei number? sim number? some unique iphone id (that is global and not just for the app)?

Comment: Apple no longer allows you to get that information because it allows you to uniquely track the user's device. If you do find a way to do it, your app will be rejected on AppStore. ( This is for Mac Adress too )

Comment: You should try the identifierForVendor or ask the info with a Form. I Hope this helped you :). Did you got the Answer to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take IMEI and phone number of user mobile, Apple is restricted to get these uniqueID's.

You have to store UDID in keychain. for this you have to download keychainwrapper class and store the UDID generated by above code:

```
UIDevice *device = [[UIDevice alloc]init]; 
NSString *idForVend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device identifierForVendor]];
NSLog(@"%@",idForVend);
```

follow this link it will solve your problem for sure:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459879/how-to-store-a-string-in-keychain-ios